# Injection and surjection parameters

Tags: functions

I have to find the parameter 'a' so that the function

$$f_a(x)=\begin{cases}
x-2a & x\le 2\\
ax-1 & x \gt 2
\end{cases}$$

1. Is an injection
2. Is a surjection.

For injection I derived the function and I found its
$$f'_a(x)=\begin{cases}
1 & x \le 2 \\
a & x \gt 2
\end{cases}$$

For injection the function must be monotonic and since for $x\le2$ the function is $1$ then it is an increasing function,so $a>0$? the answer in my book is $a \ge 3/4$ what condition is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For injection:

We certainly need $a>0$, also

$$f_a(2)=2-2a$$

For $x>2$, we require $$ax-1 > 2-2a$$

$$a(x+2) > 3$$

We need the above inequality to hold $\forall x > 2$,

Hence, $$a> \frac3{2+2}=\frac34.$$

Now, for surjection:

again, certainly  we need $a > 0$ to reach arbitrary large real number.

Also, we require $$2a-1 \leq 2-2a$$

in order to avoid a gap between $2-2a$ and $2a-1$.

That is $$0< a \leq \frac34$$